# Under what conditions is $K^{(2)}(t) $ continuous at $t=0$ where $K(t)$ is the cumulant generating function?

Tags: probability-theory, expected-value, moment-generating-functions, cumulants

For a random variable $X$ let
\begin{align}
K(t)= \log (E[e^{tX}]) 
\end{align}
This quantity is known as the cumulant generating function.

**Question:** What is some weak sufficient condition for
\begin{align}
K^{(2)}(t) 
\end{align}
to be continuous around $t=0$ where $K^{(2)}$ is the second derivative of $K(t)$? Specifically, I am interested in some conditions in terms of moments of $X$.

**Some thoughts**

Here is one condition that I think is very strong and can be imroved: Suppose that the root-test condition is satisfied
\begin{align}
 \lim_{k \to \infty}   \left( \frac{k!}{ |E[ X^k]| }\right)^{1/k}=r>0
\end{align}
Then the moment generating function $E[e^{tX}]$ is analytic for $(-r,r)$ and therefore $K^{(2)}(t)$is continuous around $t=0$.

I am curious if it is enough to have $E[X^2]<\infty$ or $E[|X|^3]<\infty$.

Also, let $\phi(t) =E[e^{tX}]$
\begin{align}
K^{(2)}(t)=\frac{\phi(t) \phi''(t) - (\phi'(t))^2}{(\phi(t))^2}.
\end{align}
So this question is equivalent to finding conditions for the continuity of the second derivative of the moment generating function.